# Zend_Db_Select for update/delete query's

Tags: php, mapping, zend-framework

While working on a mapping structure for our applications we ran into some trouble regarding the code consistency. While it's easy to make select query's with the Zend_Db_Select class (with functions like: $select->from('table')->where('id=?,1), it wouldn't work for update/delete query's. There isn't a class like Zend_Db_Update or Zend_Db_Delete to build the update and delete query's like you build the select. To fix this we extended the Zend_Db_Select class as you can see in the code below. The code shows the custom class that extends the Zend_Db_Select class with some minimal example code at the bottom to show how it's used.

```
<?php
class Unica_Model_Statement extends Zend_Db_Select
{
    public function __construct($oMapper)
    {
        parent::__construct($oMapper->getAdapter());
        $this->from($oMapper->getTableName());
    }


    /**
     * @desc Make a string that can be used for updates and delete
     *       From the string "SELECT `column` FROM `tabelnaam` WHERE `id` = 1" only the part "`id = `" is returned. 
     * @return string 
     */
    public function toAltString()
    {
        $sQuery = $this->assemble();        // Get the full query string
        $sFrom = $this->_renderFrom('');    // Get the FROM part of the string

        // Get the text after the FROM (and therefore not using the "SELECT `colname`" part)
        $sString = strstr($sQuery,$sFrom);

        // Delete the FROM itself from the query (therefore deleting the "FROM `tabelnaam`" part)
        $sString = str_replace($sFrom, '', $sString);

        // Delete the word "WHERE" from the string.
        $sString = str_replace('WHERE', '', $sString);

        return $sString;
    }
}

################################################
# Below code is just to demonstrate the usage. #
################################################

class Default_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $person = new Unica_Model_Person_Entity();
        $statement = new Unica_Model_Statement($person->getMapper());
        $statement->where('id = ?' , 1);
        $person->getMapper()->delete($statement);
    }
}

class Unica_Model_Person_Mapper
{
    public function delete($statement)
    {
        $where = $statement->toAltString();
        $this->getAdapter()->delete($this->_tableName,$where);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine using this class but it got us wondering if we were maybe missing something. Is there a reason there aren't default update/delete classes like there is for select and will using this class give us trouble elsewhere?

Advice would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance,

Ilians

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class is fine if you are sure you are not going to make it evolve too much in the future. I assume your approach is to benefit from the automatic quoting in the `Zend_Db_Select` class. In my humble opinion, however, it has some design pitfalls that could lead to extensibility troubles if you need to modify or extend it:

- It's receiving some data that is discarded afterwards (the entity object, to use the "from" clause).
- It's manipulating directly the SQL output of the `select` query, which can be something dangerous to rely upon. If the format changes, and also if you need to include more elements to the `where` clause, your code could get quite "muddy" to adapt to the changes.

My approach would just be to use the `where` clauses directly in the code, and quote them wherever it's necessary. It doesn't look particularly less clean to me. Something like the following:

```
$db->delete('tablename', 'id = ' . $db->quote('1'));
```

Eventually, you could even abstract it into a method or class, to avoid having to spread `$db->quote()` calls all over the place, something like that:

```
private function myDelete($tableName, $fieldName, $fieldValue)
{
    $this->db->delete($tableName, $fieldName . ' = ' . $db->quote($fieldValue));
}
```

**EDIT**: Including multiple clauses in the `where` part would make it a bit more involved, and how flexible you want to be will depend on your particular application. For instance, a possible solution for several "ANDed" clauses could be the following:

```
private function myDelete($tableName, array $fields)
{
    $whereClauses = array();
    foreach ($fields as $fieldName => $fieldValue) {
       $whereClauses[] = $fieldName . ' = ' . $db->quote($fieldValue);
    }
    $this->db->delete($tableName, implode(' AND ', $whereClauses));
}

$this->myDelete('tablename', array('id' => '1', 'name' => 'john'));
```

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks for  the reply, you're right about the quotes. I'm trying to automatically quote everything so the programmer won't have to bother quoting everything (and it's safe even if he forgets). However, how would the myDelete function work with multiple values in the where? Like: "DELETE WHERE id = 3 OR adress = 'test' AND language != 'EN'

Comment: Depending on how complicated the WHERE clause is, you'll need to adapt the code more or less. I've edited my answer to use only "AND" and field equality, just to show a simple example.

Comment: I tried a similar approach before but found myself stuck with the problem of similar array keys. Like the situation:
array(
  'id' => 3,
  'id' => 4
)
Used it like this though to enable greater than posibilities
array(
   'id = ?'=>3,
   'id = ?'=>4
)

Comment: As I said, I think you'll need to narrow the problem to include only the "probable" values you'll get on the where, otherwise you risk to overcomplicate the solution. If you need to handle the case of an identifier adopting several possible values, you could do it like that: array('id' => array('3', '4')). But again, the complexity will depend on the range of possible "where" cases in your application.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know the exact reasoning behind `Zend_Db_Select` not offering CUD methods. The obvious explanation is that *Select* means you should use it for just that: dynamic query building. To insert, update and delete you would either use `Zend_Db_Adapter` or the proxy methods to it in `Zend_Db_Table` and `Zend_Db_Table_Row` or the generic `Zend_Db_Statement`.

However, with that said, I think there is nothing wrong with extending `Zend_Db_Select` and adjusting it your needs (just like any other component that doesnt do what you want initially)